# Status error 500 when I access my app on a server

Tags: javascript, nginx

I want to preface this by saying this is the first time I am putting an application on a server. I followed a tutorial and was able to create a hello world app which when I access the server through its private ip I get a response saying "hello world"

Hello world app

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello Ricky\n');
}).listen(3000, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

this app is was run through the command "pm2 start hello.js", but when I try to repeat the process with my actual app I get a 500 error

My app

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('nodetest1:server');
var http = require('http');


var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);



var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);


function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

This is my Nginx configuration file

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        server_name _;
}


    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

Where do I start for trouble shooting this? A 500 error is too broad to understand, how can I access an error log to see what caused the 500?

Comment: This doesn't help a ton, but in my experience, 500 errors are typically a problem with the application itself rather than web server configuration. So, I would focus on the app. See if there is a way you can enable error logging.

Comment: Error logging! I have trying to figure out how to do that, but I can't seem to figure it out